# HAL_DELAY stuck after pvPortMalloc

Tags: stm32, freertos, hal

Environment:
STM32F103ZET6
FreeRTOS Kernel V10.3.0
MDK or arm-none-eabi-gcc

My program stopped working when I added a queue to receive messages from RS232. I managed to reproduce the problem with the following code:

```c
void initial() {
    System_Init();
    SysTick_Init(NULL);
    void *ptr = pvPortMalloc(1); // won't stuck any more if I comment this line
    HAL_Delay(10); //stuck in an infinite loop // HAL_GetTick() always returns zero
    led_init();
}
```

Any ideas?

`ptr` became 0x20003320 after the assignment. Looks fine.

This is a part of my linker script:

```
/* Entry Point */
ENTRY(Reset_Handler)

/* Generate a link error if heap and stack don't fit into RAM */
_Min_Heap_Size = 0x00000800; /* required amount of heap  */
_Min_Stack_Size = 0x00000800; /* required amount of stack */ 
/* Highest address of the user mode stack */
PROVIDE(_estack = ORIGIN(RAM) + LENGTH(RAM));

/* Specify the memory areas */
MEMORY
{
    FLASH (rx)  :ORIGIN = 0x08000000, LENGTH = 512K
    RAM (xrw)   :ORIGIN = 0x20000000, LENGTH = 64K
}
```

A part of FreeRTOSConfig.h:

```c
#define configUSE_PREEMPTION        1                             //1使用抢占式内核,0使用协作式内核(时间片)
#define configUSE_TICKLESS_IDLE     0                             //1低功耗模式,0系统节拍中断一直运行
#define configUSE_IDLE_HOOK         1                             //使用空闲任务钩子函数
#define configUSE_TICK_HOOK         1                             //使用心跳钩子函数
#define configCPU_CLOCK_HZ          ( SystemCoreClock )           //CPU时钟频率
#define configTICK_RATE_HZ          ( ( TickType_t ) 1000 )       //心跳频率,1S中断次数
#define configMAX_PRIORITIES        ( 12)                         //最大优先级数(0~configMAX_PRIORITIES-1)
#define configMINIMAL_STACK_SIZE    ( (uint16_t) 128 )            //最小栈空间大小
#define configTOTAL_HEAP_SIZE       ( ( size_t ) ( 40 * 1024 ) )  //堆空间大小
#define configMAX_TASK_NAME_LEN     ( 16 )                        //最大任务名长度
#define configUSE_TRACE_FACILITY    1                             //1启动可视化跟踪调试
#define configUSE_16_BIT_TICKS      0                             //定义节拍计数器变量类型,是16位还是32位(1 16位  0 32位)
#define configIDLE_SHOULD_YIELD     1        //1表示用于任务与空闲任务共享优先级时,用户任务就绪,空闲任务立刻让出CPU控制权
```

systick.h:

```c
#ifndef SYSTICK_H
#define SYSTICK_H

#include "stm32f1xx.h"
#include "stm32_types.h"
#include "stm32f1xx_hal.h"

typedef struct 
{ 
    void (*Operation)(void);  //中断中运行的函数
}_SysTick_Info;

extern _SysTick_Info SysTick_Info;
void SysTick_Init(void (*ISR)(void));

#endif /* SYSTICK_H */
```

systick.c:

```c
#include "systick.h"
#include "FreeRTOS.h"
#include "task.h"

extern void xPortSysTickHandler(void);

_SysTick_Info SysTick_Info;

void SysTick_Handler (void) {           
    HAL_IncTick();
    if (xTaskGetSchedulerState() != taskSCHEDULER_NOT_STARTED) {
        xPortSysTickHandler();
    }
    if (SysTick_Info.Operation != NULL) SysTick_Info.Operation();
}

void SysTick_Init(void (*ISR)(void)) {
    SysTick_Info.Operation = ISR;
    //Initialize System Tick with 1ms time interval 
    SysTick_Config(HAL_RCC_GetHCLKFreq()/configTICK_RATE_HZ);
}
```

Comment: It seems strange to me that you would pass NULL to SysTick_Init. Does it generate a warning of any kind? And what is the function declaration?

Comment: I added some code. It's a callback function.

Comment: OK. So you are checking if .Operation is NULL before calling. Well, just out of curiosity, did you check to see if ptr == NULL after calling pvPortMalloc()? I guess something must be going wrong inside pvPortMalloc().

Comment: When you pause your debugger while your program is in the HAL_Delay infinite loop, what does it show you? Is it waiting for the HAL counter to reach a value which never happens? Have you confirmed that SysTick is actually running?